# Why is the go compiler flagging my variable as unused?

Tags: go, concurrency

*my first question on StackOverflow* :D

I am running on go 1.16. I created this function:

```golang
func (_m *MyPool) InChannel(outs ...chan interface{}) error {
    for _, out := range outs {
        out = _m.inChan
    }
    return nil
}
```

MyPool is a worker pool type, containing, among other members:

```golang
type MyPool struct {
    inChan          chan interface{}
}
```

My main problem is Go is flagging the `out` loop variable when ranging over the Variadic input of `InChannel`. Why is that? I am indeed using it...

Sorry, I am a noob at StackOverflow, so I am editing to clarify a bit. I indeed want to assign, not send. This is because the sender will have an `outChan chan interface{}` as a member variable, and will send values via:

```golang
func (s *Sender) Out(out interface{}) {
    select {
    case <-s.Ctx.Done():
        return
    case s.outChan <- out:
        return
    }
}
```

EDIT: So I ended up solving it by doing:

```golang
func (m *MyPool) InChannel(outs ...*chan interface{}) error {
    for _, out := range outs {
        *out = m.inChan
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Isn't `out <- _m.inChan` what you actually want to do? or perhaps `_m.inChan <- out`? Or what do you expect to achive with `out = _m.inChan`?

Comment: Also, while it's not *wrong* in any sense, the name `_m` for the receiver variable is not very good Go style: `m` would be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not "really" using it. You assign something to a variable which you don't read, so the assignment has no effect, so basically you're not using the variable.

Note that `=` is [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments). If you want to send something on the channel, use the [send](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements) statement:

```
out <- _m.inChan
```

Or maybe you want to change the value `out` represents? `out` is a loop variable, it's a copy of the slice elements you range over. Assigning a value to `out` only assigns a value to the loop variable, but not to the slice element.

In general you may change slice elements by assigning a value using an [index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) like this:

```
s := []int{1, 2, 3}
for i := range s {
    s[i] = 10 // Assign a value to the slice elements
}
```

In your case however this would do no good, since you're ranging over the slice of the variadic parameters.

Comment: Very interesting, I assume this is due to the variadic input? If I do not use a variadic input, the assignment does take effect, correct?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the variadic parameter. You have a loop variable `out` to which you assign a value, yet you never read that variable. So it has no use, it's classified as "unused". Go does not allow unused variables.

Comment: *"the assignment does take effect"* -- @eloib not it doesn't, `out` in `InChannel` is a copy of the caller's value, all you're doing is assigning to the copy, the caller's value won't change. Use pointer indirection if you have to do something like that.

Comment: Thank you all! Sorry for the confusion, I have the same method for the `MyPool` type created, as it does contain `inChan chan interface{}`, however the method was implemented on a MyPool pointer receiver, so it totally makes sense that a chan pointer would be needed!!